# No summer funding, what to do during the summer?

Tags: phd, funding

If a STEM field PhD student is not able to be funded for the summer, what do they typically do?  I'd imagine they can't afford to take an entire summer off from their research - or they would probably risk not graduating in the standard 5 years in a U.S. program - but at the same time it would be hard for them to support themselves, eg, cover rent and living expenses, if they aren't supported by their parents / family.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/89903/what-should-a-graduate-student-be-doing-in-the-summer/89904#89904). They can also take the time to relax and maybe take up a new hobby. Grad school isn't just about research.

Comment: My question asks specifically for the case where a PhD student fails to secure summer funding from their school @seanroberson.

Comment: Road trip!!!!!!

Comment: Five years is not "standard."  It may be a common goal, but it is not commonly achieved in the US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your specific field, and when you've found out summer funding isn't guaranteed or available, I present main options in no particular order:

- Research internship in 'industry' ($ to $$$$$)
- Apply for summer grants to work in another University in different, but hopefully related, research ($ to $$)
- Get a summer job or non-research internship - ideal if it uses some set of related skills to your PhD, but if not, oh well, bills to pay ($ to $$$+)
- As Dawn suggested, a sub-set of summer job is to seek the option to be an instructor, summer teaching assistant, or grader in your University (or a nearby institution), or even being an adjunct for the summer if that option is available to you ($ to $$)
- Vacation, travel, relax rejuvenate, try some hobbies, spend time with friends and family (-$ to -$$$$)
- Focus on your own personal research, free of official obligations (at least -$, due to living expenses)
- Have an existential crisis due to the lack of driving structure which otherwise distracts you from your morality/mortality and the uncertainty inherent in life itself (free, and can stack with other options)
- Choose your own adventure

Above all, I suggest planning ahead - if not for this summer, then for the next one. Most outcomes are uncertain, so judicious planning for multiple applications, budgeting (so you have options on how to spend your summer), and trying to develop a number of options will be important.

Note also that many of the options don't need to - and perhaps should not - take up the entire summer, so you should have the option to try out multiple things. Remember: academic life is a marathon, which extends off into the unknown future until you fade away (go Emeritus) or leave ("go into industry"). That makes the longest ultra-marathon on earth seem short by comparison. No matter what you do, try to change things up a bit, work in some rest and contemplation, friends and family, and a bit of fun for yourself too. If academic life starts to resemble a 24/7/365.25 prison sentence, you might want to reconsider your worldview.

Comment: A subset of "Get a summer job" would be: Work as a summer instructor for the department or a grader.

Comment: @Dawn Good suggestion - added it!

Comment: *Have an existential crisis due to the lack of driving structure which otherwise distracts you from your morality and the uncertainty inherent in life itself* -- Who says this is just for the summer months? ;-)

Comment: For the -$ research option, which I am most interested in so that the student can finish in 5 years, what do these students typically do?  Take out a student / personal loan to hold them over for the summer months?

Comment: @user73946 The advanced planner will have saved up some money during their undergrad days.  After that, saving money for the summer months from your paid months is the easiest solution, though how easy that is depends on what the cost of living where you're living is (relative to your income), and how indulgent you normally are.  It's cheaper than a loan in the long run.  If you've got a convenient lease that ends at the summer (plausible with university housing), you could just move home with mom and dad!

Comment: @user73946 It certainly varies by person, but the short version is either have saved up money from previous work, take loans, or best: build a 12-month cost budget that includes summer, using only the 9 months of pay you get, automatically saving each "paycheck" what you need and spending only according to the budget (not according to what's in the account). In building this, you might find there isn't enough money - so you increase income (jobs, gigs, grants/fellowships) or you cut expenses (live cheaper, get roommates, etc.), ask for help, or accept it isn't an option and work around it.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy - I take it you are not in the U.S.  Undergraduate study in the U.S. does not leave one with a positive bank balance.

Answer (score -4):

Is the school trying to tell you something? Like go away? If so leave.
Assuming not Change Advisors
If your advisor is so poorly funded that he can't afford a summer stipend, there is no chance he can afford to equip his lab, and this really does not bode well for his future, and you're probably going down in flames with him if you stay

Comment: -1, as this doesn't really answer the question (regardless of whether or not it may be true).

Comment: And includes many unreasonable assumptions.